# Python Selenium compilation error

Tags: python, selenium

I just set up my eclipse / python plugin / selenium plugin and gave a try at a fist test script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

However i get the following error:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x0169C690>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 141, in __del__
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 120, in stop
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 95, in send_remote_shutdown_command
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 887, in _find_spec
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

On Mozilla the script runs with no error.
On Chrome the script runs with the error from above but finishes.
On IE the script runs with the error from above but does not finish.

Do you have any idea why is this behavior happening to me ?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [open problem](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1476) reproduced on Python 3 + selenium 2.49 + Chrome.

As a workaround, *downgrade to selenium 2.48*:

```
pip3 install selenium==2.48
```